# How does "fine_tune_checkpoint" in config file work for train.py in TensorFlow object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I downloaded the pre-trained network from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). If I directly run the some validation script with it, the average precision is ~58% for ssd_inception_v2_coco model.

However, if I try to re-train the same network with the downloaded files pointed as fine_tune_checkpoint in the config file, the initial loss value will be quite high (~300.0). Also, the detection precision becomes ~40% after only 5000 training steps.

After searching the explanation online for a while, I found some people said that not all parameters values are loaded/saved since "from_detection_checkpoint" is set to true. However, I cannot set it to false without the complaints about missing parameters value either.

Therefore, I got a little confused. If not all parameters values are saved, how can the object detection network work with it in the validation? On the contrary, if all values are saved, why it cannot be loaded as from_detection_checkpoint=false? Does the training script reset some parameters values on default? I feel that I might misunderstand something above. Any information will be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Facing a similar issue.